# C pointer, 2d matrix return

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define _USE_MATH_DEFINES
#include <math.h>


// OMNI Encoder value -0.000000, -0.268890, 3.781295, -0.000106, -2.366794, 0.250667

float encoder[6] = {-0.000000f, -0.268890f, 3.781295f, -0.000106f, -2.366794f, 0.250667f};
float d_g[6] = {0.125f, 0, 0.2f, 0.1325f, 0, 0.039f};
float a_g[6] = {0, 0, 0.134f, 0, 0, 0};
float alpha_g[6] = {0, -M_PI/2, 0, M_PI/2, -M_PI/2, -M_PI/2};


#define ARR_ROW_SIZE 4
#define ARR_COL_SIZE 4

float(*MM())[4];
float(*DH_Master())[4];
float(*FK_Master())[4];
void PrintArray(float(*arr)[4], int row, int col); 

void PrintArray(float(*arr)[4], int row, int col){

    for (int i = 0; i < row; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < col; j++){
            printf("%f ", arr[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}


// Matrix Multiplication 

float(*MM(float M1[][4], float M2[][4]))[4] {

    static float C[4][4] =      {
        { 0.000f        , 0.000f      , 0.000f      , 0.000f      }, 
        { 0.000f        , 0.000f      , 0.000f      , 0.000f      }, 
        { 0.000f        , 0.000f      , 0.000f      , 0.000f      }, 
        { 0.000f        , 0.000f      , 0.000f      , 0.000f      }};

    float tmp; 

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
            tmp = 0.0f; 

            for (int k = 0; k < 4; k++) {
                tmp += M1[i][k] * M2[k][j];
            }
            C[i][j] = tmp; 
        }
    }
    return C;
}

float(*DH_Master(float alpha, float a, float d, float theta))[4]{
    printf("alpha %f / theta %f / a %f / d %f\n", alpha, theta, a, d);

    float T_a[4][4] = {
        { 1.000f        , 0.000f      , 0.000f      , a           }, 
        { 0.000f        , 1.000f      , 0.000f      , 0.000f      }, 
        { 0.000f        , 0.000f      , 1.000f      , 0.000f      }, 
        { 0.000f        , 0.000f      , 0.000f      , 1.000f      }};

    float T_d[4][4] = {
        { 1.000f        , 0.000f      , 0.000f      , 0.000f      }, 
        { 0.000f        , 1.000f      , 0.000f      , 0.000f      }, 
        { 0.000f        , 0.000f      , 1.000f      , d           }, 
        { 0.000f        , 0.000f      , 0.000f      , 1.000f      }};

    float Rzt[4][4] = {
        { cosf(theta)   , -sinf(theta), 0.000f      , 0.000f      }, 
        { sinf(theta)   ,  cosf(theta), 0.000f      , 0.000f      }, 
        { 0.000f        , 0.000f      , 1.000f      , 0.000f      }, 
        { 0.000f        , 0.000f      , 0.000f      , 1.000f      }};

    float Rxa[4][4] = {
        { 1.000f        , 0.000f      , 0.000f      , 0.000f      }, 
        { 0.000f        , cosf(alpha) , -sinf(alpha), 0.000f      }, 
        { 0.000f        , sinf(alpha) ,  cosf(alpha), 0.000f      }, 
        { 0.000f        , 0.000f      , 0.000f      , 1.000f      }};

    float(*C1)[4] = MM(Rxa, T_a);
    float(*C2)[4] = MM(C1, T_d);
    float(*C3)[4] = MM(C2, Rzt);
    PrintArray(C3, ARR_ROW_SIZE, ARR_COL_SIZE);

    printf("//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////\n");

    return C3;  
}


float(*FK_Master(float encoder[]))[4]{
    printf("T01\n");
    float(*T01)[ARR_COL_SIZE] = DH_Master(0, 0, 0.125, encoder[0] -M_PI/2);
    printf("T12\n");
    float(*T12)[ARR_COL_SIZE] = DH_Master(-M_PI/2, 0, 0, encoder[1]);
    printf("T23\n");
    float(*T23)[ARR_COL_SIZE] = DH_Master(0, 0.134, 0.2, encoder[2]);
    printf("T34\n");
    float(*T34)[ARR_COL_SIZE] = DH_Master(M_PI/2, 0, 0.1325, encoder[3]);
    printf("T45\n");
    float(*T45)[ARR_COL_SIZE] = DH_Master(-M_PI/2, 0, 0, encoder[4]);
    printf("T56\n");
    float(*T56)[ARR_COL_SIZE] = DH_Master(-M_PI/2, 0, 0.039, encoder[5]);

    printf("T01\n");
    PrintArray(T01, ARR_ROW_SIZE, ARR_COL_SIZE);

    float(*T02)[ARR_COL_SIZE] = (MM(T01, T12));
    printf("T02\n");
    PrintArray(T02, ARR_ROW_SIZE, ARR_COL_SIZE);

    float(*T03)[ARR_COL_SIZE] = (MM(T02, T23));
    printf("T03\n");
    PrintArray(T03, ARR_ROW_SIZE, ARR_COL_SIZE);

    float(*T04)[ARR_COL_SIZE] = (MM(T03, T34));
    printf("T04\n");
    PrintArray(T04, ARR_ROW_SIZE, ARR_COL_SIZE);

    float(*T05)[ARR_COL_SIZE] = (MM(T04, T45));
    printf("T05\n");
    PrintArray(T05, ARR_ROW_SIZE, ARR_COL_SIZE);

    float(*T06)[ARR_COL_SIZE] = (MM(T05, T56));
    printf("T06\n");
    PrintArray(T06, ARR_ROW_SIZE, ARR_COL_SIZE);

    return 0;  
}


int main(void) {

    float(*Art)[ARR_COL_SIZE] = FK_Master(encoder);

    return 0;

}
```

Let me explain the problem.

Previously, I have calculated in MATLAB or Python environment.

I'm going to pay again using C this time.

I do two-dimensional matrix operations several times, and I'm writing a code that returns the calculated values again.

To put it simply,
Use a, d, alpha, theta defined at the top to perform two-dimensional matrix operations, T01, T12, ... We are writing a code that computes T01 * T12 * T23 * T34 * T45 * T56 after obtaining a total of 6 values by T56.

However, the current computation results are not coming out properly.

I'd really appreciate it if you could help me with the problem.

I will attach the correct calculated result as a picture.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g8kVY.png)

Comment: There are no "2d matrices" in C.

Comment: “the current computation results are not coming out properly” is not an adequate problem description. You should identify a specific problem, and you should reduce it to one small test case.

Comment: @gspr: The fact that C provides not fundamental type that is a two-dimensional matrix does not mean one cannot implement two-dimensional matrices in C, any more than it means you cannot have linked lists, hash tables, or other data structures in C. “Two-dimensional matrix” is commonly understood to mean an array of arrays. C 2018 6.2.5 20 specifically allows for types derived from other types, such as arrays of arrays.

Comment: I would recommend you split up your calculation, and verify each step on its own. Then you should be able find the error quite fast.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: Of course. But this contrasts sharply with the asker's experience with Matlab (where 2d matrices are arguably *the* fundamental datatype) and Python (where he presumably involved NumPy).

Comment: Picture is for explaining what cannot be represented as text. There are many demerits in images of text. The calculation result can be represented as text, so it should be posted directly as text. more info: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question? - Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: You always should use typedef for function pointers or the code quickly turns unreadable.

Comment: How did you solved this compilation error? `gcc matrix.c
matrix.c:58:8: error: conflicting types for ‘DH_Master’
 float(*DH_Master(float alpha, float a, float d, float theta))[4]{
        ^~~~~~~~~
matrix.c:58:1: note: an argument type that has a default promotion can’t match an empty parameter name list declaration
 float(*DH_Master(float alpha, float a, float d, float theta))[4]{
 ^~~~~
matrix.c:18:8: note: previous declaration of ‘DH_Master’ was here
 float(*DH_Master())[4];`